# how to fix dll registration error with msi?

Tags: installation, msi, windows-installer, dll

there is a setup file created by installshield, so used silent switch and deployed the application.
newer version of same exe is available now, when deployed with silent switch, during upgrade it is giving an error with registration of dll.
But with fresh install it is working fine.
even with gui install also, not just silent, this issue is coming.
once the error is received, when ran the regsvr32 command again, then it is succesful.
Why it is failing duirng installation?
Any tools to backtrack that?
There are many depenndencies, so extracting msi is not a feasible option at present.

Comment: What software is this? There are sites with tips on software deployment issues: https://www.itninja.com/software-library/

Comment: so you mean, I should not post questions related to windows installer/msi related posts here?

Then why the tags exist?

And what is the need of product name, when the question is generic, related to dll registrations

Comment: No, that was not what I intended to say. I was thinking you could look up your software name using that site to see if the problem is a known issue. It sounds to me like the installer fails to replace some dependency file during the upgrade and the following registration of the COM file fails for this reason, but it could be something else.

Comment: thanks for clarifying and sorry for misunderstanding. this is inhouse application, where the installation required vc++ 2017 and we kept that in dependencies of the installshield wrapper exe, so before installing the msi the vc++ gets installed. That is working, but during installation, the dll is not getting registered when we kept in custom action also. But once it completed the install and ran the cmd then it is working, strange to see what is the issue. Development team claims this is not there issue as the command regsvr32 executes successfully after installation.